# Logger source file location - openbravoErp

Tags: log4j, openbravo

```
package org.openbravo.erpCommon.utility;

import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.openbravo.data.FieldProvider;
import org.openbravo.database.ConnectionProvider;

import org.openbravo.data.UtilSql;
import org.openbravo.service.db.QueryTimeOutUtil;
import org.openbravo.database.SessionInfo;
import java.util.*;


class MessageBDData implements FieldProvider {
static Logger log4j = Logger.getLogger(MessageBDData.class);
  private String InitRecordNumber="0";
  public String msgtype;
  public String msgtip;
  public String msgtext;
```

Above is a source code of class MessageBDData found in `/opt/OpenbravoERP-3.0/openbravo-erp/build/javasqlc/src/org/openbravo/erpCommon/utility`

Well, I need to find source code of Logger `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;`which is imported in above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot directly the source code of `import org.apache.log4j.Logger` because it is coming from the `log4j` jar file

for more info on `org.apache.log4j.Logger` visit [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) manual.